# XBAP + Error .....System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Tags: deployment, xbap

I am able to execute application sucessfully in the server but whn i acess the XBAP file after publishing from bin folder i get the below error. Even i am not able to access the application in the client machines. Will it be the same reason, if so how do i rectify this issue??

```
Startup URI: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\DesignSystem\ProLaser.Windows.xbap
Application Identity: file:///C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/DesignSystem/ProLaser.Windows.xbap#ProLaser.Windows.xbap, Version=1.2.0.33, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fa7c3f587c5c81e0, processorArchitecture=msil/ProLaser.Windows.exe, Version=1.2.0.33, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fa7c3f587c5c81e0, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Cannot create instance of 'AdminControl' defined in assembly 'ProLaser.Windows, Version=1.0.4385.21840, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  Error in markup file 'ProLaser.Windows;component/AdminControl.xaml' Line 1 Position 14. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ProLaser.Windows.AdminControl..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.CreateInstanceFromType(Type type, Int16 typeId, Boolean throwOnFail)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, Uri baseUri, XamlObjectIds currentXamlObjectIds, XamlObjectIds contextXamlObjectIds, Type objectType)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(ParserContext parserContext, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, String message, Exception innerException)
   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ThrowExceptionWithLine(String message, Exception innerException)
   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.CreateInstanceFromType(Type type, Int16 typeId, Boolean throwOnFail)
   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.GetElementAndFlags(BamlElementStartRecord bamlElementStartRecord, Object& element, ReaderFlags& flags, Type& delayCreatedType, Int16& delayCreatedTypeId)
   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.BaseReadElementStartRecord(BamlElementStartRecord bamlElementRecord)
   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadElementStartRecord(BamlElementStartRecord bamlElementRecord)
   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadRecord(BamlRecord bamlRecord)
   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.Read(Boolean singleRecord)
   at System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilderBamlTranslator.ParseFragment()
   at System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilder.Parse()
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.AppModelKnownContentFactory.BamlConverter(Stream stream, Uri baseUri, Boolean canUseTopLevelBrowser, Boolean sandboxExternalContent, Boolean allowAsync, Boolean isJournalNavigation, XamlReader& asyncObjectConverter)
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.MimeObjectFactory.GetObjectAndCloseStream(Stream s, ContentType contentType, Uri baseUri, Boolean canUseTopLevelBrowser, Boolean sandboxExternalContent, Boolean allowAsync, Boolean isJournalNavigation, XamlReader& asyncObjectConverter)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.GetObjectFromResponse(WebRequest request, WebResponse response, Uri destinationUri, Object navState)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.DoNavigate(Uri source, NavigationMode f, Object navState)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigateQueueItem.Dispatch(Object obj)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.StartDispatcherInBrowser(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)


-----------------------

PresentationHost.exe v3.0.6920.1427 built by: SP - C:\WINDOWS\system32\PresentationHost.exe
ntdll.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
kernel32.dll v5.2.3790.4062 (srv03_sp2_gdr.070417-0203) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
ADVAPI32.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
RPCRT4.dll v5.2.3790.4115 (srv03_sp2_gdr.070709-2335) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
Secur32.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
MSVCR80.dll v8.00.50727.3053 - C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.3053_x-ww_B80FA8CA\MSVCR80.dll
msvcrt.dll v7.0.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
USER32.dll v5.2.3790.4033 (srv03_sp2_gdr.070228-0030) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
GDI32.dll v5.2.3790.4237 (srv03_sp2_gdr.080215-1206) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
ole32.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
mscoree.dll v2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\mscoree.dll
SHLWAPI.dll v6.00.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
urlmon.dll v7.00.6000.16705 (vista_gdr.080618-1506) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\urlmon.dll
OLEAUT32.dll v5.2.3790.4202 - C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
iertutil.dll v7.00.6000.16705 (vista_gdr.080618-1506) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\iertutil.dll
SHELL32.dll v6.00.3790.4184 (srv03_sp2_gdr.071106-1258) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
WININET.dll v7.00.6000.16705 (vista_gdr.080618-1506) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\WININET.dll
Normaliz.dll v6.0.5441.0 (winmain(wmbla).060628-1735) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\Normaliz.dll
IMM32.DLL v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
comctl32.dll v6.0 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.3790.3959_x-ww_D8713E55\comctl32.dll
MSCTF.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
CLBCatQ.DLL v2001.12.4720.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
COMRes.dll v2001.12.4720.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMRes.dll
VERSION.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
xpsp2res.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\xpsp2res.dll
netapi32.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\netapi32.dll
ws2_32.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ws2_32.dll
WS2HELP.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
dfshim.dll v2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\dfshim.dll
mscorwks.dll v2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000) - C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
PresentationHostDLL.dll v3.0.6920.1427 built by: SP - C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\WPF\PresentationHostDLL.dll
PSAPI.DLL v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
msi.dll v4.5.6001.22159 - C:\WINDOWS\system32\msi.dll
actxprxy.dll v6.00.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\actxprxy.dll
SXS.DLL v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\SXS.DLL
PresentationHostProxy.dll v3.0.6920.1427 built by: SP - C:\WINDOWS\system32\PresentationHostProxy.dll
ieproxy.dll v7.00.5730.13 (longhorn(wmbla).070711-1130) - C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll
apphelp.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\apphelp.dll
msctfime.ime v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\msctfime.ime
mshtml.dll v7.00.6000.16705 (vista_gdr.080618-1506) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\mshtml.dll
msls31.dll v3.10.349.0 - C:\WINDOWS\system32\msls31.dll
msimtf.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\msimtf.dll
UxTheme.dll v6.00.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\UxTheme.dll
IEFRAME.dll v7.00.6000.16705 (vista_gdr.080618-1506) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\IEFRAME.dll
jscript.dll v5.7.0.5730 - C:\WINDOWS\system32\jscript.dll
ImgUtil.dll v7.00.5730.13 (longhorn(wmbla).070711-1130) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ImgUtil.dll
pngfilt.dll v7.00.6000.16705 (vista_gdr.080618-1506) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\pngfilt.dll
mlang.dll v6.00.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\mlang.dll
mscorlib.ni.dll v2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000) - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\mscorlib\9adb89fa22fd5b4ce433b5aca7fb1b07\mscorlib.ni.dll
System.ni.dll v2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000) - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System\aa7926460a336408c8041330ad90929d\System.ni.dll
WindowsBase.ni.dll v3.0.6920.1427 built by: SP - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\WindowsBase\df20e56b59b1b1a595af305ddc0777ba\WindowsBase.ni.dll
PresentationCore.ni.dll v3.0.6920.1427 built by: SP - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\PresentationCore\12dcb10b76012416357bdbb010fdaa97\PresentationCore.ni.dll
PresentationFramework.ni.dll v3.0.6920.1427 built by: SP - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\PresentationFramewo#\9519494798a88867406b5755e1dbded6\PresentationFramework.ni.dll
wpfgfx_v0300.dll v3.0.6920.1427 built by: SP - C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\WPF\wpfgfx_v0300.dll
PresentationUI.ni.dll v3.0.6920.1427 built by: SP - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\PresentationUI\87fb973e4ab6a21fd00e45656fa7c115\PresentationUI.ni.dll
msimg32.dll v5.2.3790.0 (srv03_rtm.030324-2048) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\msimg32.dll
System.Deployment.ni.dll v2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000) - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Deployment\df1efcbac5973454c608890f72eb994d\System.Deployment.ni.dll
shfolder.dll v6.00.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\shfolder.dll
rsaenh.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
System.Configuration.ni.dll v2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000) - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Configuration\cb4cb21d14767292e079366a5d3d76cd\System.Configuration.ni.dll
System.Xml.ni.dll v2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000) - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Xml\36f3953f24d4f0b767bf172331ad6f3e\System.Xml.ni.dll
System.Security.ni.dll v2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000) - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Security\0418eb6dbffe9b46aa4c989153d6a3b5\System.Security.ni.dll
CRYPT32.dll v5.131.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\CRYPT32.dll
MSASN1.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSASN1.dll
cryptnet.dll v5.131.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\cryptnet.dll
WLDAP32.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\WLDAP32.dll
SensApi.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\SensApi.dll
USERENV.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\USERENV.dll
mshtmled.dll v7.00.6000.16705 (vista_gdr.080618-1506) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\mshtmled.dll
System.Drawing.ni.dll v2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000) - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Drawing\6978f2e90f13bc720d57fa6895c911e2\System.Drawing.ni.dll
System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll v2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000) - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Windows.Forms\9a254c455892c02355ab0ab0f0727c5b\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll
mscorjit.dll v2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000) - C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorjit.dll
PresentationFramework.Classic.ni.dll v3.0.6920.1427 built by: SP - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\PresentationFramewo#\ef1a93d10c3a91b728745dbfcc79c2c7\PresentationFramework.Classic.ni.dll
System.ServiceModel.ni.dll v3.0.4506.2152 (SP.030729-0100) - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.ServiceModel\d85d9535e91da842fded56869d57790a\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
d3d9.dll v5.3.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d9.dll
d3d8thk.dll v5.2.3790.0 (srv03_rtm.030324-2048) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d8thk.dll
WINMM.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
rasapi32.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasapi32.dll
rasman.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasman.dll
TAPI32.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\TAPI32.dll
rtutils.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\rtutils.dll
msv1_0.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\msv1_0.dll
iphlpapi.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\iphlpapi.dll
mswsock.dll v5.2.3790.4318 (srv03_sp2_gdr.080620-1216) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
hnetcfg.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll
wshtcpip.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll
DNSAPI.dll v5.2.3790.4318 (srv03_sp2_gdr.080620-1216) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
winrnr.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
rasadhlp.dll v5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
WindowsCodecs.dll v6.0.5840.16388 (winmain(wmbla).061024-1209) - C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
SMDiagnostics.ni.dll v3.0.4506.2152 (SP.030729-0100) - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\SMDiagnostics\2e19ccefc30d7b827bab3f7d8dcc0ab9\SMDiagnostics.ni.dll
System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll v3.0.4506.2152 (SP.030729-0100) - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Runtime.Seri#\bb748f8ef8c98eb5c7f79b8faee95397\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll
System.Web.ni.dll v2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000) - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Web\50ea744ffc3cb7f09b027fd6c5c93b2b\System.Web.ni.dll
System.WorkflowServices.ni.dll v3.5.594.1152 - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.WorkflowServ#\43911ac4e29949c57560eee5cb7b76c2\System.WorkflowServices.ni.dll
System.ServiceModel.Web.ni.dll v3.5.594.1152 - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.ServiceModel#\a3adabee8e63dc76f65710a9c32175fc\System.ServiceModel.Web.ni.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.dll v9.0.30729.1 - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink\3.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.dll
System.IdentityModel.ni.dll v3.0.4506.2152 (SP.030729-0100) - C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.IdentityModel\94b2ca600c860c76e387f8bd317bd4c3\System.IdentityModel.ni.dll
diasymreader.dll v8.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000) - C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\diasymreader.dll
```